# React router v4 not working on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Im having trouble with react-router-dom working in production. While my app header and footer are rendered just fine, the router does not work and I can see the following comments where my routes should appear upon inspecting the html in Chrome devtools. I am getting no console errors.

```
<div>
  <!-- react-empty: 15 -->
  <!-- react-empty: 16 -->
  <!-- react-empty: 17 -->
  <!-- react-empty: 18 -->
</div>
```

This is my App.js component file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import styled from 'styled-components';

import Header from 'components/Header';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';

import Home from 'containers/Home';
import Select from 'containers/Select';
import Process from 'containers/Process';
import Privacy from 'containers/Privacy';

const AppWrapper = styled.div`
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: calc(768px + 16px * 2);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

class App extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <AppWrapper>
                    <Header/>
                        <div>
                            <Route exact path='/' render={({history}) => 
                                <Home infoHandler={this.handleUserInfo} 
                                    imageHandler={this.handleImage} 
                                    history={history}/>
                            }/>
                            <Route exact path='/select' render={({history}) =>
                                <Select info={this.state.userInfo} 
                                    image={this.state.userImage}
                                    selectionHandler={this.handleSelectedImage}
                                    history={history}/>
                            }/>
                            <Route exact path='/process' render={({history}) => 
                                <Process image={this.state.selectedImage} user={this.state.userInfo}/>
                            }/>
                            <Route exact path='privacy' component={Privacy}/>
                        </div>
                    <Footer/>
                </AppWrapper>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from 'containers/App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The router works like a charm in dev mode. Using Webpack for building.

** Home Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import FacebookLogin from 'components/FacebookLogin';
import {Row, Col} from 'react-flexbox-grid';

import styled from 'styled-components';
import palette from 'palette';

const Img = styled.img`
    max-width: 100%;
`;

const H3 = styled.h3`
    color: ${palette.black};
`;

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Row center='xs'>
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <Img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/julsgc/image/upload/v1491106020/Boletia_995x380__2_fqawa8.png"/>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <h3> A que Ser Extraordinario te pareces!? </h3>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <p> Averigualo ahora! </p>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <FacebookLogin 
                        infoCallback={this.props.infoHandler}
                        imageCallback={(data) => {
                            this.props.imageHandler(data);
                            this.props.history.push('/select');
                        }}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    history: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Home;
```

*** Update ***

App is now working after switching to hash router. Any further comments appreciated since BrowserRouter is the recommended approach according to the docs.

Comment: This may help, or it may make things worse. I've looked over your code and it looks fine. Not sure what's going on. Curious, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I have not figured it out yet. [This] thread mentions that the comments are React's way of handling a null component, if I understood correctly. I added the code to the Home Component that should be rendered, maybe that can shed some light on the error? Many thanks :)

Comment: Ran into same issue, HashRouter works fine, but not BrowserRouter, still looking for solution.

Comment: Are you overriding the SCU (shouldComponentUpdate) function in the code you've missed out (...) by any chance?

Comment: I found this thread about a month ago, had the same problem, although different setup. The problem seemed to have stemmed off of having multiple versions of react and react-router installed by dependencies. After stabilizing all versions of react / react-dom / react-router / etc., and nuking the node_modules, the problem went away.

Comment: Updating BrowserRouter to HashRouter works find for me either, but I don't know why it is...

Answer (score 4):

use below code in httacces file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

if your app not in root folder then use

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/the-app">
```

**also more review check link 
https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-browserrouter-on-apache/

Comment: Thanks, This should be the accepted answer. My project is in a subdirectory and adding the `basename` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look on this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178712/react-routing-not-working-while-manually-changing-url-react-router-4)

If u are using Webpack, then just add -

```
devServer{
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

And for `gulp` use the following:

```
historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

//start a local dev server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: ['dist'],
    port: config.port,
    base: config.devBaseUrl,
    livereload: true,
    middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Original question specifies that "The router works like a charm in dev mode.". Your answer addresses `devServer` and `devBaseUrl` only (a.k.a. "dev mode"). Rather than skimming over questions and just copying and pasting from other threads, please take the time to understand the issue and respond accordingly.