# Routes are not valid when using basename property of Router on production mode

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using this Router:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || '/MyApp'}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        {/*<Redirect path="*" to="/" />*/}
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

When working with dev mode (npm start), it's working and redirecting as expected.

When working with production mode (npm build --> copy the output of build to WebContent folder on a war to be deployed on tomcat), it behaves differently:

- http://host:port/MyApp is working fine, and routing using the app is fine too
- routing manually by typing the route value on the browser, e.g. 
  http://host:port/MyApp/login is giving: Page can't be found.

(Note: typing the route manually in dev mode working fine)

Why it differs? How it can be solved?

## What I had tried:

Reference: [React routing not working while manually changing URL | React-router 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178712/react-routing-not-working-while-manually-changing-url-react-router-4)

adding devServer entry (with historyApiFallback: true) to my webpack.config.prod.json:

```
export default {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    // To support react-hot-loader
    alias: {
        'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
},
devtool: 'source-map', // more info:https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#source-mapping and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/,
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `historyApiFallback: true` does is it renders `index.html` if the requested file doesn't exist. Your production webserver is not doing this, so when it attempts to load `/MyApp/login`, it see that there is no file called `/MyApp/login` (or `/MyApp/login/index.html` depending on configuration) and returns a 404.

Since React Router is handling your routing logic client side, you need to set up your webserver to fallback to delivering `index.html` if it can't find a page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's make sense. Adding this to my web.xml did the work : <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>